# iOS Safari, when running our web-app in stand alone mode, crashes iOS in background

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, iphone-web-app

We're developing a web app that extensively uses Cavas 2D for some demos, and is successfully running on both iOS and Android devices. Recently we've added stand-alone mode for iOS devices, so user has to "Add-To-Home-Screen" and run it using screen icon, just like regular app.

What happens recently is that after 10-12 times we start the web app on iPhone4:

1. Status bar (initially set to 'black') suddenly turns white and we cannot exit Safari (by pressing home button).
2. If we try to make screen shot (home + power button), shutter sound is played as if screen shot was taken and saved.
3. If we try to lock the device (power button), screen turns black, but no action after that can bring unlock-screen or any screen for that matter - display remains black.
4. We can only do reset by pressing home + power for 10 seconds after this point.
5. If we do not lock the device, web app continuously work with no issues at all, it does not crash, but cannot exit it (double click on home button also has no result).

Has anyone experienced this with their web apps?

Any guidance in how to debug this would be highly appreciated. We've tried using Safari on OSX, connect iPhone to it and use Develop -> iPhone menu but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow!  This sounds like a weird one... you may want to file a Radar on it.  Can you elaborate on what happened when you tried the Safari Web Inspector (you say "no luck so far")?  Did it not connect, or could you not reproduce the crash with SWI connected?

Comment: @Arkaaito You are corect, when connected with SWI, so far the issue would not manifest. We're trying it just now, if it happens while connected to SWI, will post any results there may be.

Answer (score 1):

I would start trying to debug by running XCode with the iPhone connected to the computer.

In XCode open "Organizer" and go to the tab "Devices".

You should see your device there, from which you can view the iOS console.  That might be able to tell you what is going wrong with the phone stops responding.

I don't think you have to put the phone in development mode (or be a paid developer) to see the iOS console.